Software for Desktop Customization
I’m looking for software that allows me to customize my desktop in a highly personalized way.
Here are my requirements:

Must work on Windows (preferably Windows 11).
Lightweight, so it doesn’t significantly impact system performance.
Ideally free or with a reasonable one-time cost.

So far, I know about Rainmeter, which seems to be one of the most popular options for desktop customization. While it looks powerful, I’m curious if there are other alternatives I should consider, especially those with simpler setup processes or different feature sets.

What does it need to do, except setting a desktop wallpaper?
